# Generate random Colors in Bar chart with Plotly Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I am using Plotly for Python to generate some stacked bar charts. Since I have 17 objects which are getting stacked, the colour of the bars has started repeating as seen in the image below.

[image: Bar Chart]
[image]

Can someone tell me how to get unique colours for each stack?

Please find my code to generate the bar chart below:

```
import plotly
plotly.tools.set_credentials_file(username='xxxxxxxx', 
api_key='********')
dd = []
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np


for k,v in new_dict.items():

    trace = go.Bar(x = x['unique_days'],
                       y = v,
                       name = k,
                       text=v,
                       textposition = 'auto',
                      )
    dd.append(trace)




layout= go.Layout(
    title= 'Daily Cumulative Spend per campaign',
    hovermode= 'closest',
    autosize= True,
    width =5000,
     barmode='stack',
    xaxis= dict(
        title= 'Date',
        zeroline= False,
        gridwidth= 0,
        showticklabels=True,
        tickangle=-45,
        nticks = 60,
        ticklen = 5
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        title= 'Cumulative Spend($)',
        ticklen= 5,
        gridwidth= 2,
    ),
    showlegend= True
)
fig = dict(data=dd, layout = layout)

py.iplot(fig)
```

Comment: Hi Sumedha, did you get something done? I am also working on generating some random based colors for plotly gantt chart but i cant get it working solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It was the issue which I have been facing in this week and I solved with Matplotlib module. Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib, random

hex_colors_dic = {}
rgb_colors_dic = {}
hex_colors_only = []
for name, hex in matplotlib.colors.cnames.items():
    hex_colors_only.append(hex)
    hex_colors_dic[name] = hex
    rgb_colors_dic[name] = matplotlib.colors.to_rgb(hex)

print(hex_colors_only)

# getting random color from list of hex colors

print(random.choice(hex_colors_only))
```

There are 148 colors in the list and you can integrate this list with your wish. Hopefully it is useful for someone :)

Comment: Thanks a ton ! that worked :)

Answer (score 2):

the same as above, short version:

```
import matplotlib, random
colors = dict(matplotlib.colors.cnames.items())
hex_colors = tuple(colors.values())
print(hex_colors)
#getting a random color from the dict
print(random.choice(hex_colors))
```