# Trying to create colors dynamically for a Gantt Chart

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, gantt-chart

I am trying to figure out how to get a different color for each unique 'Task' in a dataframe.  Is there a way to do that?  As you can see here, all my colors are hard-coded.  I would like to get the colors generated dynamically.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import plotly.figure_factory as ff


color = ['#B0171F',
        '#DC143C',
        '#FFB6C1',
        '#FFAEB9',
        '#EEA2AD',
        '#CD8C95',
        '#8B5F65',
        '#FFC0CB',
        '#FFB5C5',
        '#EEA9B8',
        '#CD919E',
        '#8B636C',
        '#DB7093',
        '#FF82AB',
        '#EE799F',
        '#CD6889',
        '#8B475D',
        '#FFF0F5',
        '#EEE0E5',
        '#CDC1C5',
        '#8B8386',
        '#FF3E96',
        '#EE3A8C',
        '#CD3278',
        '#8B2252',
        '#FF69B4',
        '#FF6EB4',
        '#EE6AA7',
        '#CD6090',
        '#8B3A62',
        '#872657',
        '#FF1493',
        '#EE1289',
        '#CD1076',
        '#8B0A50',
        '#FF34B3',
        '#EE30A7',
        '#CD2990',
        '#8B1C62',
        '#C71585',
        '#D02090',
        '#DA70D6',
        '#FF83FA']

fig = ff.create_gantt(df, colors=color, index_col='Task',
                      show_colorbar=True, bar_width=0.3, showgrid_x=True, showgrid_y=True, group_tasks=True, show_hover_fill=True)

fig.show()
```

This code produces the chart shown below.

[image]

Comment: Could this help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53436786/generate-random-colors-in-bar-chart-with-plotly-python

Comment: It worked perfect!  I'll share the final version of code below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a final version of the code that works.

```
df = df_final
df.rename(columns = {"real_estate_complete": "Start"}, inplace=True)
df.rename(columns = {"construction_started": "Finish"}, inplace=True)
df.rename(columns = {"local_market": "Task"}, inplace=True)
n = df.Task.nunique()

import matplotlib, random

hex_colors_dic = {}
rgb_colors_dic = {}
hex_colors_only = []
for name, hex in matplotlib.colors.cnames.items():
    hex_colors_only.append(hex)
    hex_colors_dic[name] = hex
    rgb_colors_dic[name] = matplotlib.colors.to_rgb(hex)

color = random.sample(hex_colors_only, n)

import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

fig = ff.create_gantt(df, colors=color, index_col='Task',
                      show_colorbar=True, bar_width=0.3, showgrid_x=True, showgrid_y=True, group_tasks=True, show_hover_fill=True)

fig.show()
```

[image]